# Unable to login to Vault via CLI

Tags: hashicorp-vault, vault

When I try to log in to Vault using the CLI:

```
vault login ${MY_SUPER_SECRET_TOKEN}
```

I get the error: `Error authenticating: empty response from lookup-self`

I am able to log in via the UI using a Token or OIDC.

`vault read auth/token/lookup-self` looks OK.

Setup is the same as other Vault setups that are CLI-working but I can't seem to pin down where the error is in this one.

Comment: Is it everything OK when you run "vault status"?

Comment: Getting `Error checking seal status: Get "https://{URL}/v1/sys/seal-status": dial tcp: lookup {URL} on {IP_ADDRESS}: server misbehaving`

Comment: Maybe this can helps: https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way/issues/630

Comment: did you correctly configure the VAULT_ADDR, VAULT_TOKEN, VAULT_CACERT, VAULT_CLIENT_CERT, VAULT_CLIENT_KEY, environment variables?

Answer (score 1):

The error was related to the Vault server being unreachable due to firewall.